# How to run least confident based uncertainty sampling

Tags: machine-learning

This is a rather open-ended question. I am currently using Classify to run a Random Forest and I would like use an active learning algorithm on it. The most conducive would be least confident based uncertainty sampling, I have been unable to find any built-in functions on this.

Would you be able to point me to any material on how to do this?